# Make a macro script in cmake and call that macro in source file

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it possible to create a macro in cmake. And that macro will be call in the C++ source files. Like,

```
#include path(file.h)
```

This path() was defined in a cmake file. I think it will generate the definition in the generated makefiles.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need variables from CMake's scope, you can use [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3aconfigure_file)

If you need code generation, I think it's not possible to use CMake's macros. Use other language (sh or python) to write code generator and add_custom_command to your CMakeLists.txt